# Get data from MongoDb and insert in a file

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I built the next files:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use("/", function(request, response){
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("Test");
    dbo.collection("users").findOne({},function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    var name = result.name;
    response.render('index',{ name});
    db.close();
  });
});
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="result"><%=name %></h1>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the first name of users from my database:MongoDb, and i insert it  `<h1 class="result"><%=name %></h1>`. How to get all names from database? Now i get only the first.

Answer (score 0):

So, As far as I could understand the question it is You want to get the first name of all the users in the collection users .
If that is what you are looking to achieve. May be we should understand first as to why we are only getting one User. It could very well be because of the method.

```js
dbo.collection("users").findOne({},function(err, result) {});
```

As the name suggest findOne will only return one object that matches the criteria given as the first argument to the methdo findOne which in Our case is simply {}. So, In Our case it would return the very first User in User collection. To get the list of all the Users simply change findOne to simply find. Which In Our case would then be :

```js
dbo.collection("users").find({},function(err, result) {});
```